# Dois tipos de pesquisa numa mesma textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados

Gostaria de saber se é possível pesquisar dois tipos de variáveis(uma de cada vez) em uma só textbox. Exemplo:

```
public ActionResult Index(string pesquisa)
{
    var usuario =  from u in db.usuario
                  select u;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pesquisa))
    {
        usuario = usuario.Where(p => p.nomecompleto.Contains(pesquisa));
    }

    return View(usuario);
}
```

Esse meu código acima retorna os usuários cadastrados do site de acordo com o nome. Eu gostaria que o administrador do site tivesse a opção de pesquisar os usuários tanto pelo nome quanto pelo CPF (que foi definido como `int`), simplesmente digitando o nome ou CPF.

Alguém poderia explicar se é possivel fazer isso? E se possível, gostaria de aproveitar o código acima.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível. Basta fazer com que sua string de pesquisa pesquise também pelo CPF.

Não conheço sua classe de Usuário, mas suponho que ela tem um campo `CPF` que é uma `String` já formatada, e o que vem da tela também é uma `String` de CPF já formatada dentro do campo `pesquisa`:

```
public ActionResult Index(string pesquisa)
{
    var usuario =  from u in db.usuario
                  select u;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pesquisa))
    {
        usuario = usuario.FirstOrDefault(p => p.nomecompleto.Contains(pesquisa) || p.cpf.Contains(pesquisa));
    }

    return View(usuario);
}
```

Comment: Tem Alguma diferença entre usar o Where  ou o FirstOrDefault?

Comment: Sim, o `FirstOrDefault` já devolve o primeiro elemento da pesquisa passada como predicado, ou `null` se não houver resultados. O `Where` devolve um elemento iterável que precisa de outros métodos para se tornar o resultado desejado. Para o seu caso, `FirstOrDefault` é o mais recomendado.